# Swift App crashes after archive when using currentLocale and userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nslocale

I am in a strange situation of app crash after archiving the app and installing on a device. There are many other similar posts on SO with same headline I believe but here is what is happening with my app -

In AppDelegate, I have the below -

```
func loadInitialViews () {

        let deviceLanguage = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String

        DDLogVerbose("Device Language:\(deviceLanguage)")

        let xtraStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if (appLanguageStatusDefault == false) {

            if ((deviceLanguage != "fr") && (deviceLanguage != "nl")) {
                let myInitialVc = xtraStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("languageVc")
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
                self.window?.rootViewController = myInitialVc
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

            else {
                defaults.setValue(deviceLanguage, forKey: defaultsKeys.appLanguage)
                defaults.setBool(true, forKey: defaultsKeys.appLanguageStatus)

                defaults.synchronize()


                let s = UIStoryboard (
                    name: "LoginStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: UserLoginViewController.self)
                )

                frameworkViewController = s.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewControllerId") as? UserLoginViewController

                frameworkViewController!.appUrl = "\(requestProtocol)://\(requestDomain)/\(requestBase)/\(requestVersion)/\(appLanguageDefault)/customer/logon?client=iziapp"

                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
                self.window?.rootViewController = frameworkViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                frameworkViewController!.viewControllerId = "loginViewController"

            }
        }

        else {
            defaults.setValue(appLanguageDefault, forKey: defaultsKeys.appLanguage)
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: defaultsKeys.appLanguageStatus)

            defaults.synchronize()


            let s = UIStoryboard (
                name: "LoginStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: UserLoginViewController.self)
            )

            frameworkViewController = s.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewControllerId") as? UserLoginViewController

            frameworkViewController!.appUrl = "\(requestProtocol)://\(requestDomain)/\(requestBase)/\(requestVersion)/\(appLanguageDefault)/customer/logon?client=iziapp"

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = frameworkViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            frameworkViewController!.viewControllerId = "loginViewController"
        }
}
```

My app crashes after I archive and install it on the device. And the app crash info (by using NSZombieEnabled) says that there is a crash at appLanguageDefault. Here are details  from device crash log -

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Xtra                            0x001b7700 globalinit_33_F56DB677A89F23933EFF171487480023_func9 (AppDelegate.swift:49)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x23da3caa _dispatch_client_callout + 22
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x23da489a dispatch_once_f + 62
3   Xtra                            0x0006ea4c AppDelegate.loadInitialViews() -> () (AppDelegate.swift:0)
4   Xtra                            0x0007124c specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift:120)
5   Xtra                            0x0006e028 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift:0)
```

**What am I trying achieve?**

1. Launch the app
2. Check language of device (to see if fr or nl is the device language).
3. If it is fr or nl, then the appLanguageDefault is set to one of these. appLanguageStatusDefault is set to true (that means, a language is already set for the app). And, then login screen is shown.
4. If it is any language other than fr or nl, then a language selection screen is shown. appLanguageDefault is set to selected language. appLanguageStatusDefault is set to true, and then the login screen is shown.

The above process works well when I install the app on device through Xcode, and on simulator. But the app crashes when I archive and install on a device.

Can someone help on figuring out this crash?

**UPDATE1:** There are no problems with my devices/profile/certificate because am able to upgrade install on my previous version. If user is already loggedIn while upgrade install, then the app runs with other screens normally. Issue is only at the logon flow in AppDelegate's `loadInitialViews()`

Comment: How do you came to know that it is crashing because of appLanguageDefault?

Comment: From the crashlog, it shows crash at AppDelegate Line 120. And global init at line 49 is the place where I initialized appLanguageDefault

Comment: Can you just print some thing before that line and after that line to confirm that the crash is happening on that line.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?